# Getting data from JSON ( AngularJS)

Tags: json, angularjs, html

I've got the whole questions that I have in my JSON file, but I need only one until the user will click the right answer and go to the next one

HTML template:

```
<div ng-controller="quizController">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="q in allData">
        <h1 id="question">{{q.question}}</h1>
    </li>
</ul>


<div class="answers">
    <a class="btn btn-primary"><p>New York</p></a>
    <a class="btn btn-warning"><p>Miami</p></a>
    <a class="btn btn-success"><p>Washington</p></a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger"><p>LA</p></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller("quizController", function($scope, $http){
$http.get("questions.json")
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.allData = response.data;
    });
});
```

JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "question": "Which is the largest country in the world by population?",
    "options": ["India", "USA", "China", "Russia"],
    "answer": 2
  },
  {
    "question": "When did the second world war end?",
    "options": ["1945", "1939", "1944", "1942"],
    "answer": 0
  },
  {
    "question": "Which was the first country to issue paper currency?",
    "options": ["USA", "France", "Italy", "China"],
    "answer": 3
  },
  {
    "question": "Which city hosted the 1996 Summer Olympics?",
    "options": ["Atlanta", "Sydney", "Athens", "Beijing"],
    "answer": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: You could use Node or PHP to serve questions 1 by 1, also it's a better practice to send back from the Back end only the question and options and when the user answers to check the selected option with the backend. By getting the whole json I can inspect the Request and find out the correct answer

Comment: @StefanosChrs So there is no other solution without using Back End?

Comment: You can't hide the response data so the user can see the answer no matter how you store it in the JSON.. You could implement an endpoint in node for example /question and in there you can pick a random question and return it. So the response of the http will have only the current question and options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to mindparses approach but goes a little deeper. You can navigate back and forth. It's not full proof but should help you on your way.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="quizController">
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="quizController">
        <p>
            <h1 id="question">{{currentQ.question}}</h1>
            <div class="answers">
                <ul ng-repeat="option in currentQ.options">
                    <li>{{option}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </p>
        <button ng-click="move(-1)">Previous</button>
        <button ng-click="move(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS/CONTROLLER**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("quizController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.move = function (direction) {
        // you're gonna need an IF block here to stop it from going out of range.
        var position = $scope.allData.indexOf($scope.currentQ);
        $scope.currentQ = $scope.allData[position + direction];
    }

    $http.get("questions.json").then(function(response){
        $scope.allData = response.data;
        $scope.currentQ = $scope.allData[0];
    });    
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/xyprn1dr/)**

Comment: Can I do this leaving my four buttons, and have my JSON filled each of it with answer?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can do whatever you want really. If I'm getting you right, you want the answers prefilled/selected even before it's answered? Update!

Comment: You can handle the design yourself. As long as the logic works. For the possible answers/options just use an ng-repeat and CSS to display and style them. My solution was just to give you starting point

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean

Answer (score 1):

You should not use ng-repeat then, since this will just loop through your questions and show them all at once in the UI.

Instead, store your questions array in another variable and then bind your UI to a specific index of that variable.

```
app.controller("quizController", function($scope, $http){

$scope.allData = [];
//Initially set to first element (question), then you will need to increment in further logic elsewhere probably on a button click handler if the answer is correct    
$scope.currentQuestion =  $scope.allData[0];

$http.get("questions.json")
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.allData = response.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: So I remove ng-repeat and need to bind with {{currentQuestion}} ?

Comment: Yes, that way you can control which number question is showing in the UI.